# What does "-" mean as an argument to a command?

Tags: command-line, tar

I found this link on how to [open tgz in one step](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/65/decompress-and-extract-a-tgz-or-targz-archive-in-a-single-step/).

```
gzip -dc target.tar.gz | tar xf -
```

What does the '-' mean?

Comment: Also, most versions of tar now support gzip and bzip natively. For a gzip-ed tar file `tar xfz target.tar.gz` and for bzip `tar xfj target.tar.bz2`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's a common convention to use `-` in a filename argument to mean `stdin` or `stdout`; `tar` follows the same convention. From the man page:

```
   -f, --file [HOSTNAME:]F
          use archive file or device F (default "-", meaning stdin/stdout)
```

Comment: This is only a convention; you need to read the manpage for the particular command to see what `-` means to it.  Stdin/stdout is by far the most common meaning, but there are others.  For instance, to some versions of `env` it means "start with an empty environment".

Answer (score 0):

Another convention is to use '-' to indicate the end of flags, and the beginning of file names.  That behavior is built-in to the getopt(3) on RedHat 4, at least. I can't find a Red Hat man page that uses '-' to indicate end-of-arguments, they all seem to use '--' to do that.  The awk man page has '--' in that context, so maybe only old "heirloom" Unix or Solaris commands use '-' as a arguments - file names separator.

Comment: `--` signals the end of options, so everything that comes afterwards is an operand. `-` is not an option, so it and everything that comes afterwards is an operand. This is [standard behavior](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getopt.html). For many commands, such as `tar`, [the operand `-` means standard input or output](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9361/9363#9363). On many shells, `set - -a` is equivalent to `set -- -a`, and on some old Bourne shells `set - -a` was the only accepted form, but this an exception with the `set` built-in.

Comment: Solaris programs mainly follow the POSIX standard convention of `--` to separate options from arguments.